# Sharepoint 2013 OOTB Search box

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Is there any way that i can customize default sharepoint Search box to get results only of specific content type.

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" />
```

Some property in above tag where i can key in my "content type" to limit search only from this content type.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might have an easier time configuring the Query on the Search Results Webpart as described on this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-settings-for-the-Search-Results-Web-Part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e#__define_the_query

The Search Results Webpart has the Query Builder, where you would input something like:

```
{searchTerms} ContentType=yourcontenttype
```